# Command line search using tracker database

Tags: command-line, tracker

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I understand there are no GUIs to interact with `tracker`'s database.

**Is there a way to perform a search for contents in tracker's database via command line?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple...

```
$ tracker search <regex>
```